# Show the first X results in Group Concat

Tags: mysql, limit, group-concat

I have a query that returns a list of items that an owner has:

```
WITH all_items
AS
  (
         SELECT owner.id AS owner,
                item.title,
                item.importance
         FROM   owner
         JOIN   item
         ON     item.owner_id = owner.id)
  SELECT   owner.id,
           group_concat(DISTINCT item.title ORDER BY item.importance SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM     owner
  JOIN     all_items
  ON       all_items.owner = owner.id
```

I need to limit the group_concat to max of 6 items. I can't do LIMIT in all_items because it returns only the top 6 items, regardless of who the owner is. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is `substring_index()`:

```
substring_index(group_concat(DISTINCT item.title ORDER BY item.importance SEPARATOR ','), ',', 6)
```

Your query is missing a `GROUP BY` and seems overly complicated.  I have no idea why you are joining back to the `owner` table again.  In fact, you don't need to join to it at all.  Why not just use this?

```
SELECT i.owner_id AS owner,
       group_concat(DISTINCT i.title ORDER BY i.importance SEPARATOR ',')
FROM item i
GROUP BY i.owner_id;
```

You can get the first six using a different method as well:

```
SELECT i.owner_id AS owner,
       group_concat(DISTINCT i.title ORDER BY i.importance SEPARATOR ',')
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.owner_id ORDER BY i.importance DESC, i.title) as seqnum
      FROM item i
     ) i
WHERE seqnum <= 6
GROUP BY i.owner_id;
```

This has the advantage that you don't have to worry about `GROUP_CONCAT()` string limits (assuming the titles are not very long) when an owner owns zillions of items.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your answer, the first part helped me big time, I didn't remember that, it's super smart!

The reason it's so complicated is that it's just a part of a bigger thing and I simplified it so I could easily explain what is it exactly that I need. TL;DR, the main owner is parametrized and gets data from over 20 tables, so I chunked them in order to be able to make future additions/fixes without disrupting what already is in motion. 

Thanks again! <3

Comment: By the way, RANK is completely alien to me, but I see it mentioned around a lot, I'll definitely get to read more about it this weekend, seems super useful!